# PHP - how to create some column/field depending on another row table

Tags: php, mysql

there's some way to create column depending by another row?

I mean like this :

example:

I have `table A`:

```
|----|----------|
| id | criteria |
|----|----------|
| 1  | column A |
| 2  | column B |
| 3  | column C |
| .. |    ...   |//column D, E, F, etc
|----|----------|
```

how to create a `Table B` like this?

```
|column A |column B |column C | ... |
|---------|---------|---------|-----|
|  value  |  value  |  value  |(etc)|
|   ...   |   ...   |   ...   | ... |
|---------|---------|---------|-----|
```

is it possible with PHP??

> I don't know a keyword of this case, so if someone wanna give me a link, it would be appreciate

Comment: Is this being sourced from SQL? Are you expecting this to be the result from SQL? We need more details...

Comment: @Enstage i don't understand what you mean, because im not good in english and programming language too, can you give me a hint of your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can get Criteria from Table A by SELECt query, Assume that you know the SELECT Query, and after that based on result You can run loop for each Criteria get from table A. and for add column Use below query.

```
IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT NULL
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
           WHERE table_name = 'tablename'
             AND table_schema = 'db_name'
             AND column_name = 'columnname')  THEN

  ALTER TABLE `TableName` ADD `ColumnName` varchar(255) ;

END IF;
```

Comment: above query is for php script or i can try on SQL? and what the meaning of `information_schema.column`?